# How to install & configure snakemake for the Azure environment

Tags: azure, snakemake

I am new to both snakemake and Azure cloud computing. My org has set me up with an Azure batch account, resource group, and storage account. I have successfully moved my data into an Azure blob. I would like to use snakemake to implement my analyses, and I have some very basic questions - like whether snakemake and its dependencies should be installed locally or on an Azure VM, and how to correctly set up the config file.

I searched the snakemake documentation and came up empty on these questions.  I would greatly appreciate any suggestions and advice from someone who has successfully used snakemake with Azure batch, Azure blobs, etc. Thank you!

Comment: If you're developing and testing small-scale workflows, installing Snakemake locally on your machine is a good start. For larger, more compute-intensive workflows or for production runs, installing Snakemake on an Azure VM is recommended. This enables you to leverage Azure's compute resources. Kindly refer to [MSDoc](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/introducing-snakemake-for-azure-batch/ba-p/3850649) for setup on azure

Answer (score 0):

To  [install & configure snakemake for the Azure environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77958013/how-to-install-configure-snakemake-for-the-azure-environment), you can follow the below steps-

Connect to azure via az cli
[image]

Install the related dependencies

```bash
conda create -c bioconda -c conda-forge -n snakemake snakemake 

msrest azure-batch azure-storage-blob azure-mgmt-batch azure-identity 

conda activate snakemake
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Once installed, you can verify the same using

`snakemake --version`

Reference:
[Setup Snakemake](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/introducing-snakemake-for-azure-batch/ba-p/3850649)